# How to resize a JFrame manually?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am  trying to resize the JFrame manually by dragging a JPanel. Here is what i have done.  At the moment it works, but the screen still flickers, and the resizing is not correct

What i want it to happen is, when i click on the Jpanel and drag it, the JFrame should resize automatically to where the X Coordinates and Y Coordinates are.

```
     public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    // Sets width, height and moved X and Y coordinates
    int currentwidth = this.getWidth();
    int currentheight = this.getHeight();
    int newwidth = 0;
    int newheight = 0 ;

    int thisX = this.getX();
    int thisY = this.getY();

    // Calculates the moving distance
    int xMoved = (thisX + e.getX()) - (thisX + initialClick.x);
    int yMoved = (thisY + e.getY()) - (thisY + initialClick.y);



    // Checks which component the mouse is clicked on
    if(e.getComponent() == reszingbit){

        // Calculates the new height and width
        newwidth = 200 + xMoved;

        newheight = 200 + yMoved;

        // Making sure that the new height and width is not less than actual size
        if(newwidth >= 200 && newheight >= 200){
            this.setSize(newwidth,newheight);
        }
    }
```

200 is the actual height and width.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

It is to little informations, but maybe you need, to change the size calculation to:

```
    newwidth = this.getWidth() + xMoved;

    newheight =  this.getHeight() + yMoved;
```

also the move size calculation should look like this:

```
    int xMoved =  e.getX() - initialClick.x;
    int yMoved =  e.getY() - initialClick.y;
```

Comment: I had it set to this.get height and width initially. But it seemed to go on a loop everytime I dragged the mouse. So I mean the size was the increasing really fast and not stopping while I stopped the drag. Could there be a problem with calculating the distance of the drag?

Comment: How do you normally calculate the distance of the mouse moved to increase the size of a screen?